# "Which is the correct way of writing a Planned/future Leave Request Email"?

Tags: communication, email, leave-of-absence

I need to write a leave application for taking a planned/future date leave. Which is the correct way of writing the following lines:-

1. *I won't be able to attend the office on Oct 15 as i have to go out of town.*
2. *I will be out of office on Oct 15 as i have to go out of town.*

Which is more formal and accepted way of writing? kindly help!

Comment: 'Application' is ambiguous ;-) Do you mean that you want to apply for leave? In that case, shouldn't it be a **request**?

Comment: @JanDoggen In the Indian work place at least, "leave application" is synonymous with a "request for leave of absence". Perhaps the OP works in an Indian work place.

Comment: Why you need the leave is nobody's business but your own, just request the dates...

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend making it slightly more vague in some ways(never say *why* you need/want leave) and more specific in others(be extremely explicity about the dates/times/length of time. And example:

```
I would like to request leave for the day of Thursday, November 24th 2014.
```

This does a couple of things - highlights which day of the week(so there are no confusions about timed deliverables), highlights how long(one day) and gives the specific date. In fact this could be abstracted to a template like so:

```
I would like to request TYPE_OF_LEAVE leave for AMOUNT OF TIME on START_DATE through END_DATE

TYPE_OF_LEAVE = Paid, ETO, Unpaid, etc
AMOUNT OF TIME = a rough estimate of how long you are planning on being off
START_DATE, END_DATE = the official range you are requesting off
```

If you do want to give more information then add something like *"I will/will not be available during this time via email/phone/carrier pidgeon."* is about a far as you should go. Why? If you have an embaressing or private reason for taking leave and you have gotten in the habit of saying why you want/need leave then when you don't want to say why(surgery, job interview, whatever) then you're in the position of lying which almost never turns out well.

Comment: I am confused, above you used word  _on_ & _through_ shouldn't it be _from_ & _to_. Word 'on' seem ok but confused about  'through'

Answer (score 5):

Either way is fine. You are writing a communication which is designed to be consumed in under three seconds, and either sentence works because it meets the clarity and brevity tests. I don't know how long you've been agonizing over the phrasing, but it's not worth the time or energy.

I'd replace "go out of town" with "be out of town", though. Personal bias or preference on my part? I don't know, because "go out of town" is just as clear. On the other hand, "be out of town" seems to flow more smoothly but again, my opinion may be subjective. Go with whatever phrase is comfortable to you since neither phrase leaves room for misunderstanding.